# Dagger-Hilt for older Gradle version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-hilt

For DI I am using Dagger-Hilt from [Google dev](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android).
My Hilt version is 2.28-alpha. When I sync my project, I get

> "Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 5.4.1"

At the moment my current project doesn't allow me to upgrade my old gradle version. Is there an older version than my Hilt version that is compatible with my gradle version? Is there a way around this?

Comment: @The_Marian did you find anything on this ? Even I am looking for the same. When I upgraded the gradle there were other errors related to multidex. So I am kind of stuck  here as well.

Comment: @NitinMesta that is the lowest version. Unfortunately, you have only one option to upgrade your gradle version if it is worth it for your project.